# Как реализовать метод созадния объекта с УЖЕ заданным именем?

Tags: классы, объекты, полиморфизм

Нужно сделать так ,что бы при вызове некого метода (пускай будет `createNewUser`) выводилось сообщение `"Введите имя пользователя"`(пуская введённое имя будет `vaska`), после чего создавался объект класса `Person` с именем `vaska` `Person vaska = new Person();`.

PS: не обязательно давать объектом какие-то уникальные имена.можно давать имена по типу `user1`,`user2`....

Comment: это вообще никак не относится к полиморфизму... ну совсем.

Comment: Самый главный вопрос: зачем такой бред нужен? Похоже ты не так понял задание, которое тебе где-то дали

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего тебе нужно что-то типа такого:

```
// класс Персона, которому можно задать имя
class Person {
    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // метод, чтобы отображать объект как строку
    public String toString() {
        return "Меня зовут: " + name;
    }
}


public class Test {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // заполнение списка именами
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            // в консоли вводим имя 
            String personName = scanner.nextLine();
            // создаем объект Person с введенным именем и кладем в список
            personList.add(new Person(personName));
        }

        System.out.println(personList.toString());
    }
}
```

При входных данных

```
vaska
user1
user2
```

Выведет

```
[Меня зовут: vaska, Меня зовут: user1, Меня зовут: user2]
```